# python regex find any letter or word inside underscore

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My strings can be:

```
string = 'thumbC_L_001_JOIN' 
string = 'L_thumbC_001_JOIN'

match = re.match(r'^(?:\b\w|_){}(?:\b\w|_)+'.format('L'), chain,flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    print(match)
```

I need to find the letter **L** in this case wherever it be between two underscores or at the beginning of the string with an underscore after it

Comment: Maybe `(?i)^[a-z]+_|_[a-z]+_`?

Comment: @revo where should i locate the **L** inside of that expression ?

Comment: It looks for any word (or a single letter) under required conditions. For `L` only it is `^L_|_L_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with an alternation to assert that the letter L is at the start of the string followed by an underscore or that the letter L is surrounded by an underscore:

[`^L(?=_)|(?<=_)L(?=_)`](https://regex101.com/r/aMnbRJ/1)

- `^L(?=_)` Match L and assert that what follows is an underscore
- `|` Or
- `(?<=_)L(?=_)` Assert that what is on the left is an underscore, match `L`and assert that what follows is an underscore

Comment: match = re.match(r'(?:^L(?=_)|(?<=_)L(?=_))', 'thumbC_L_001_JOIN', flags=re.IGNORECASE)  => this gives me None

Comment: this solution work if a change the **match** for **search** i will select it as solved!! thank you very much